# How to change the name of a field generated with a function in list_display in admin.py

Tags: django, django-models

i have a `modelAdmin` in admin.py. i want to display a value which i generated from a function in the model. here is the code:

```
admin.register(Salary)
class Salary(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('Category','BasicPA','BasicBM','Grade','Step','total')
    def BasicBM(self,instance):
        return instance.get_BasicBM()
    def total(self,instance):
        return instance.total()
    fieldsets =(
        ('Grade Salary Information',{
            'fields':('Category','BasicPA','RentP','TransportP','MealG','UtilityP','WeighInP','CSAP','TSAP','CallG','HazardG','RuralAllG','ShiftG','DomesticLawG','StateCounselG','Grade','Step')
            }),
        )
```

This works but it shows 'BasicBM' on the l`ist_display` title and i want to change it to 'Basic B/M'. i can't change it because i think the name of the string in `list_display` list has to match the name of the function in the class Salary in admin.py for this to work and the name of a function can't contain '/' or spaces. please, how do i achieve this? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the display decorator.  I've never used it but it seems to do what you want.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.display

```
@admin.display(
    description='Basic B/M',
)
def BasicBM(self,instance):
        return instance.get_BasicBM()
```

Comment: Thanks... it does exactly what i want